# Cloudmade API Turn by Turn - can custom voiced be used?

Tags: iphone, cloudmade

Anyone with experience using the Cloudmade api for iphone apps? I'm being asked if it's feasible to incorporate custom voices for the turn by turn navigation it offers.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can get the turn-by-turn routing as an XML ([see documentation](http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/routing-http-api/Documentation)) and feed the instructions to the Text-to-Speech engine (I'm afraid there's nothing out-of-the-box for iPhone, so I'd suggest you give a try to [Flite](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src) or a similar).

I'm not sure Cloudmade SDK does anything different than that, also incorporating some TTS engine in their SDK. For sure, this is exactly what I did for an Android application myself for turn-by-turn routing.